# add class to element if ID is greater than a certain value, while ID has concatintated text

Tags: javascript

I don't know why this feels like mission impossible, but how do we detect if an ID is of a certain value or greater, when it also has string characters tied it name?  My goal is to set a class on all rows that are greater than `row<x>` (i.e. `row6` and up). Here is what I attempted so far but feel stuck...

- Sample HTML

```html
  <tr id="row1">...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr id="row2">...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr id="row3">...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr id="row4">...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr id="row5">...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr id="row6">...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr id="row7">...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr id="row8">...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr id="row9">...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr id="row10">...</tr>
  
...etc...
```

- The script

```js
  
    //GET ALL DESIRED ROWS BASED ON THEIR ID
    var mRows = document.querySelectorAll("#datatable #datarows tr[id^='row']");

    //FOR EACH TR ELEMENT CHECK TO SEE IF THE ID ATTRIBUTE IS GREATER THAN 5
    mRows.forEach(function (mRow) {
   
      //TRYING TO GET THE ROW BASED ON ITS NUMERICAL VALUE, BUT THIS DOESN'T WORK...         
      if (mRow.id.replace('row', '').length > 5) {
           mRow.classList.add('some-class');
      }
    });

    //NOTHING CHANGED FOR ELEMENTS GREATER THAN ROW5 ADDING MY CLASS...
    console.dir(mRows);
```

Comment: If you just need the row as a numerical value, why have the `.length` property used in the comparison? Other than that, you would need to convert it to a numerical value as the `replace()` function still returns a string. You could also use regular expressions to remove any non-numerical values `parseInt(mRow.id.replaceAll(/[^0-9]/g, "")) > 5`

Comment: Many thanks @EssXTee. That length was an overlook on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.length` doesn't get the numerical value, it gets the length of the string. Use `parseInt()` to convert it to a number.

```
if (parseInt(mRow.id.replace('row', '') > 5) {
```

Comment: oh wow, thank you for that enlightenment!  learn something new every day!